# How do I create a SOAP WebService in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, soap

I want to create a SOAP WebService in an Azure environment.
The WC won't do anything fancy...just receive a SOAP request from internet and return some data retrieved from a Azure SQL DB in the same Azure instance.

Is this not a normal scenario? Because i can't find any information about it.
I have found some info on Logic Apps, Logic Connector and such, but they don't seem to fit my need. I can't find any information on how I define and create a WC in c# that i can deploy in Azure and then communicate with from internet.
Maybe it's me that have misunderstood the abilities of Azure...

Comment: You could for example deploy a WCF Service that accepts SOAP requests to a WCF Service Web Role: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nishasingh/2012/12/04/creating-and-deploying-a-wcf-service-on-windows-azure-and-consuming-it-in-windows-8-store-app/

Comment: Create a simple Wcf Web service publish it on Azure. Consume it. there is a ton of exemple around the net like [this](https://blog.brauwers.nl/2016/11/30/no-more-excuses-protect-your-azure-soaprest-api-always-end-to-end-scenario-part-1/) that will cover the create and publish part.

Comment: I found the old WCF guides...but they are way old and i thought that there were improved/new ways now, but maybe there isn't.

Comment: @merger: The "improved/new way" is to move away from SOAP.

Comment: @mm8 I know, but that isn't possible as it is a customer requirement :(

Comment: @merger: I guess your question has been answered then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SOAP isn't the preferred way to handle online communication anymore, it is still used as you are seeing. It is still supported in the .Net Framework and there are even [new features being released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/) for it.

The simplest way to host a WCF service in Azure is going to be [in App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-howto-migrate-app-service?view=azure-dotnet), particularly if what you are looking for is a simple web endpoint. As long as the bindings you are using are allowed on App Services, you shouldn't need to do anything different to deploy it to Azure.

In addition to App Services, you could simply use a VM the same as you would on prem, or something like Service Fabric if you need something that can manage a large collection of services, your SOAP endpoint included.